# How search to find what table contains data in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 database that I'm trying to pick apart and copy the relevant data into a spreadsheet. What I am trying to do is find which table in the database has peoples surnames in, as they are not in the logically named tables. How would I do a search to find what table has for example the surname `edyvane` in it.

My knowledge of SQL Server is limited so step by step instructions would be really helpful!

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

*Late answer, maybe it will be useful to other readers*

You can also try with ApexSQL Search, it’s a free tool. It can search for text within database objects (including object names), data stored in tables and views (even encrypted ones), and repeat previous searches in a single click.

In SSMS from the Object Explorer, select a database and from the ApexSQL Search main menu, choose the Text search option. This will open the Text search window, in the Search text box enter the value you want to search for (e.g. **edyvane**) and click the Find button.

If you need additional information, you can take a look at this [link](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/quickly-search-for-sql-database-data-and-objects/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s). It searches for the **structure** (not the contents) - e.g. it will find any table with a `surname` column - and that's often enough to figure out which tables you're interested in.

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Answer (score 1):

On approach, though it's a little raw, would be to run this statement:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + OBJECT_NAME(id) +
    ' WHERE ' + c.name + ' LIKE ''%edyvane%'''
FROM syscolumns c
WHERE xtype IN (35,99,167,175,231,239)
```

which will return you a listing of `SELECT` statements to run against columns that are text. You would get more than one `SELECT` for the same table, but that really doesn't matter because this is just research. You just need to get your hands dirty and find the data.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I have no understanding of what its returned or what I now do with it :(

Comment: @WebblyBrown, it returns a bunch of `SELECT` statements. Copy all of those `SELECT` statements into a query window and run them to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script I use: [search database for a specific word v2.sql - gvee.co.uk](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Search%20database%20for%20a%20specific%20word%20v2.sql)

Comment: **Usual disclaimer:** avoid using this in a production environment - it is intended for development usage.

Comment: This just returns: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types image and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Script udpated. Please try again!

Comment: Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 19
There is already an object named '#results' in the database.

Comment: Run the very last line in the script that drops the #results table. Because of the previous error the last command didn't complete.